# PHP grouped by the field

Tags: php

I have three classes: Transport, ServiceStation , CatalogTransport:

```
$service1=new ServiceStation('Service1','Address1');
$service2=new ServiceStation('Service2','Address2');
$t1=new Transport("t1",'type1',100,'carcase1','engine1','chassis1',$service1);
$t2=new Transport("t2",'type2',200,'carcase2','engine2','chassis2',$service1);
$t3=new Transport("t3",'type3',300,'carcase3','engine3','chassis3',$service2);
$catalog=new CatalogTransport();
$catalog->addTransport($t1);
$catalog->addTransport($t2);
$catalog->addTransport($t3);
$catalog->showCatalog();
```

My CatalogTranspot class:

```
class CatalogTransport{
    private $catalog = [];
    public function addTransport(Transport $t) {
        $this->catalog[] = $t;
    }

    public function showCatalog() {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->catalog);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

And my showCatalog() returns:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Transport Object
    (
        [name:Transport:private] => t1
        [type:Transport:private] => type1
        [weight:Transport:private] => 100
        [carcase:Transport:private] => carcase1
        [engine:Transport:private] => engine1
        [chassis:Transport:private] => chassis1
        [service:Transport:private] => ServiceStation Object
            (
                [name:ServiceStation:private] => Service1
                [address:ServiceStation:private] => Address1
            )

    )

[1] => Transport Object
    (
        [name:Transport:private] => t2
        [type:Transport:private] => type2
        [weight:Transport:private] => 200
        [carcase:Transport:private] => carcase2
        [engine:Transport:private] => engine2
        [chassis:Transport:private] => chassis2
        [service:Transport:private] => ServiceStation Object
            (
                [name:ServiceStation:private] => Service1
                [address:ServiceStation:private] => Address1
            )

    )

[2] => Transport Object
    (
        [name:Transport:private] => t3
        [type:Transport:private] => type3
        [weight:Transport:private] => 300
        [carcase:Transport:private] => carcase3
        [engine:Transport:private] => engine3
        [chassis:Transport:private] => chassis3
        [service:Transport:private] => ServiceStation Object
            (
                [name:ServiceStation:private] => Service2
                [address:ServiceStation:private] => Address2
            )

    )

)
```

How can I grouped it  by the field service?

I want that it will such:

Service1:

t1,t2

Service2:
t3

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: add some method that sorts your objects array in right way with array_map functions for example

Comment: Very simple approach: First you shod have a getter method for "ServiceStation" Object because name is private property. Then you can iterate $this->catalog and create an array with all "Services" objects. Pay attention at duplicates. If Service1 or Service2 are objects you should serialize them. Then iterate again $this->catalog, compare with your array and create your hiérarchie as you wish. Thus the BigO complexity will be O(2n) thus O(n) ... acceptable